# How to patch standing seam metal roof after chimney removal

Tags: roofing

House has a standing seam metal roof with unexposed fasteners. 4 feet down from the peak (just one ridgeline on a rectangle house with a shallow pitch roof, roughly 30 years old) there is a chimney I will be removing to below the roof line and there will be a roughly 3'x6' opening leftover. Previous owners left me one 25' length of roofing panel and I'm hoping I can somehow cut it into pieces to fill in the hole once I put framing into it. Sounds like these roofs are crimped together so I'm doubting I'll be able to somehow slide the replacement piece under the old ones. Is there a way to fill in this hole in the roof that won't leak, without removing the whole roof? I don't care much about how it looks.

This is similar to [Bringing unused chimney down below roof line?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/69632/bringing-unused-chimney-down-below-roof-line) with the difference being that my chimney is not at the peak, though it is still surrounded by the roof.

Comment: You should only need to remove what's above the chimney to get the new bits in position, though the sides may require more extensive (but not whole roof) disassembly. I somewhat understand them but lack practice with them so I'll leave answering to someone with more practice.

Comment: What is the chimney made out of. Is it necessary to remove the chimney or can you just remove the flu from inside and then have a metal Cover And flashing manufactured to seal  The opening without compromising the existing roof ? If the chimney needs to be removed and it is not too far from the end of the house then taking off the panels back to where the hole is  and filling the hole in with the proper decking and structure,  then re-installing full metal panels would be the way to go

Comment: It's a brick chimney with metal flu caps. Not sure where the water is coming in but has lots of efflorescence. It's 25 feet from the end of roof (in the garage). Got a quote for repointing, but don't want to invest in something I don't want to have.